# Angular Material - how to dynamically assign a context menu based on the target element

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have three buttons and three "mat-menu" menus. The "div" element used to position the context menu has "matMenuTriggerFor" which I try to dynamically assign in the component, based on which button was clicked.
However I get the following error in console: "matMenuTriggerFor: must pass in an mat-menu instance"

Is this the right approach to have different context menus based on the context?

COMPONENT.HTML

```
    <div style="border: 1px solid green; padding: 10px;">
    <p><b>Basic Menu</b></p>
    <button id="idButton1" (click)="onContextMenu($event)">Left click to open menu programmatically</button> &nbsp;
    <button id="idButton2" (contextmenu)="onContextMenu($event)">Right click to open menu programmatically</button> &nbsp;
    <button id="idButton3" (click)="onContextMenu($event)">Left click to open menu programmatically</button> &nbsp;
  </div>

  <!-- used to position the context menu. this div has 'matMenuTriggerFor' to select which menu should be used-->
  <div #contextMenuPositioningElementHash 
    id="contextMenuPositioningElement" 
    style="position: fixed;"
    [style.left]="contextMenuPosition.x" 
    [style.top]="contextMenuPosition.y" 
    [matMenuTriggerFor]="contentMenuTriggeredFor"
    [matMenuTriggerData]="{item: item}">
  </div>

  <mat-menu #contextMenu1="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item>
      <mat-icon>dialpad</mat-icon>
      Action 1.1
    </button>
    <button mat-menu-item>
      <mat-icon>voicemail</mat-icon>
      Action 1.2
    </button>
  </mat-menu>

  <mat-menu #contextMenu2="matMenu">
    <!-- <ng-template matMenuContent let-item="item"> -->
      <button mat-menu-item (click)="onContextMenuAction1(item)">Action 2.1</button>
      <button mat-menu-item (click)="onContextMenuAction2(item)">Action 2.2</button>
    <!-- </ng-template> -->
  </mat-menu>

  <mat-menu #contextMenu3="matMenu">
    <!-- <ng-template matMenuContent let-item="item"> -->
      <button mat-menu-item (click)="onContextMenuAction1(item)">Action 3.1</button>
      <button mat-menu-item (click)="onContextMenuAction2(item)">Action 3.2</button>
    <!-- </ng-template> -->
  </mat-menu>
```

COMPONENT.TS

```
    import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatMenuTrigger, MatMenu } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'biq-menu-material',
  templateUrl: './biq-menu-material.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./biq-menu-material.component.less']
})

export class BiqMenuMaterialComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.contentMenuTriggeredFor = this.contextMenu3;
  }

  items = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Item 1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Item 2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Item 3' }
  ];

  @ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger) contextMenu: MatMenuTrigger;

  @ViewChild('contextMenu1') contextMenu1: MatMenu;
  @ViewChild('contextMenu2') contextMenu2: MatMenu;
  @ViewChild('contextMenu3') contextMenu3: MatMenu;
  @ViewChild('contextMenuPositioningElementHash') contextMenuPositioningElementHash: ElementRef;

  contextMenuPosition = { x: '0px', y: '0px' };
  contentMenuTriggeredFor: MatMenu;

  onContextMenu(event: MouseEvent, item: Item) {
    event.preventDefault(); // disable browser's right click

    this.contextMenuPosition.x = event.clientX + 'px';
    this.contextMenuPosition.y = event.clientY + 'px';
    //this.contextMenu.menuData = { 'item': item };

    let targetElement = event.target as HTMLElement;
    if (targetElement.id === "idButton1") {
      this.contentMenuTriggeredFor = this.contextMenu1;
    }
    if (targetElement.id === "idButton2") {
      this.contentMenuTriggeredFor = this.contextMenu2;
    }
    if (targetElement.id === "idButton3") {
      this.contentMenuTriggeredFor = this.contextMenu3;
    }

    this.contextMenu.openMenu();
  }

  onContextMenuAction1(item: Item) {
    alert(`Click on Action 1 for ${item.name}`);
  }

  onContextMenuAction2(item: Item) {
    alert(`Click on Action 2 for ${item.name}`);
  }
}

export interface Item {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

Comment: I found two issues so far, "contentMenuTriggeredFor" needs to be initialized in ngOnInit and the second and the third "mat-menus" had ng-template elements. I updated the code in the question so now it works, however, the menu that is displayed is one step behind. Let's say we initialize the "contentMenuTriggeredFor" with "contextMenu3". First time when I click on "idButton1", the third menu is displayed. When I click second time the correct (first) menu is displayed. Then I click on "idButton2" the first menu is displayed and when i click the second time the correct (second) menu is displayed.